# I'd like to prevent componentWillUnmount like beforeunload in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to do beforeunload with React, but I cannot.
For example

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko and Trident
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko and WebKit
});
```

But, I wanna do as below

```
componentWillUnmount: function(e) {
    var result = confirm('\o/');
    if (!result) {
       // prevent unmount
    }
},
```

Comment: In react you shouldn't prevent component from unmounting, instead you should trigger a confirmation check in you routing library before refreshing/going to other page. What are you using for routing?

Comment: I see. I am using Ruby on Rails router for routing.

Answer (score 0):

[React Router Working Example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)
**Its called as preventing transition**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Prompt
} from 'react-router-dom'

const PreventingTransitionsExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Form</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/one">One</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/two">Two</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Form}/>
      <Route path="/one" render={() => <h3>One</h3>}/>
      <Route path="/two" render={() => <h3>Two</h3>}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isBlocking: false
  }

  render() {
    const { isBlocking } = this.state

    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.target.reset()
          this.setState({
            isBlocking: false
          })
        }}
      >
        <Prompt
          when={isBlocking}
          message={location => (
            `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
          )}
        />

        <p>
          Blocking? {isBlocking ? 'Yes, click a link or the back button' : 'Nope'}
        </p>

        <p>
          <input
            size="50"
            placeholder="type something to block transitions"
            onChange={event => {
              this.setState({
                isBlocking: event.target.value.length > 0
              })
            }}
          />
        </p>

        <p>
          <button>Submit to stop blocking</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default PreventingTransitionsExample
```

Answer (score -2):

Just re-mount the component, possibly in a setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() { browserHistory.push('/myComponent') }, 500);
```